# Doxygen warning format to match Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, doxygen

I have doxygen setup as a PostBuild Event in Visual Studio 2013 (C++) as a means of giving warnings about what still needs to be documented.

Does anyone know if its possible to alter the format of the doxygen warning messages

Currently the doxygen format is

> D:/project/src/MyFile.h:13: warning: Compound MyClass is not
>   documented.

But if the format were:

> D:\project\src\MyFile.cpp(63): warning Compound MyClass is not
>   documented.

Then the errors would get copied from the output into the "Error List" and also double clicking on the error in the output window would take me directly to the line where the documentation was missing

Of course I can write an application to run doxygen in the background and transform the messages (which is what I will do) but if its possible to tell doxygen to generate VS style warnings via the doxygen configuration Then I would prefer to do that.

> e.g.
>
> > path(line): message

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

Sorry to answer my own question, it seems that the doxygen configuration has the following option WARN_FORMAT

by altering it to:

> WARN_FORMAT            = "$file($line): $text"

Allows the errors to be integrated into visual studios error and output

Comment: Please, how did you change the forward slash to backslash in the output?

Comment: Problem is that the doxygen outputs the error in /path/file form instead of \path\file form that visual studio expects. So this is not working.

Comment: I have experienced the same, but only when I built doxygen myself with cygwin, however I believe, when I used a prebuilt windows binary it seemed the slashes were the correct way around... its almost as if it depends how the binary is built, but that is just a guess.

Comment: Looking at the code on github it does look like there is alot of #ifdef CYGWIN32  code and alot of slashify() and reslashify(), I suspect if it reads the path in windows style it would report the warning in windows style

Comment: @MyDeveloperDay: Fantastic. Thank you for having answered your own answer so brightly!